# Get current logged in user from WordPress + enable display errors

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

I tried everything I found to get the the current logged in user from WordPress, but it doesn't work.

Additionally, PHP isn't displaying errors anymore no matter what I do. It must have something to do with requiring WordPress files, because other scripts are displaying the errors correctly.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once("wp-config.php");

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

ini_set('error_log', 'script_errors.log');
ini_set('log_errors', 'On');

get_currentuserinfo();
print_r($current_user);
echo "end";

/*
    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
    echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
    echo 'User level: ' . $current_user->user_level . "\n";
    echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
    echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
    echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
    echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
*/

$username = $current_user->user_login);
```

Comment: Why are you manually including `wp-config.php`? Note: that doesn't actually include the WordPress core...

Comment: Because the script is outside wordpress

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed some English issues with your post.  Have you tried looking at wp-config.php to see if is setting any error related flags ?

Comment: define('WP_DEBUG', true);   is set in config

Comment: Errors are displayed in the other pages of wordpress installations and before the line get_currentuserinfo();

Comment: *"Viewed 23 times"* - but still pointed to by a search engine!!